# BERT reasoning capabilities

Tags: bert, transformer

I'm working on a Twitter classification task and while analyzing the errors I found quite a few strange predictions. I'm searching for a tool (preferably open-source) similar to https://towardsdatascience.com/how-does-bert-reason-54feb363211 that is able to compute the highest positive/negative attribution given to the words (the reason why I'm not able to use the approach presented in the aforementioned article is the price). In this way, I hope that I'll be able to better understand (and possibly correct) these misclassifications. I tried looking at the attention heads but I don't feel that I'm able to fully understand and draw conclusions based on this information.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You can use SHAP for the model interpretation.

Link: https://github.com/slundberg/shap#natural-language-example-transformers

Answer (score 0):

You can try to implement Integrated Gradients yourself (https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/interpretability/integrated_gradients), see also the [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1703.01365.pdf) for reference

Another alternative is using the attention mechanism ([Here](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/visualizing-berts-self-attention-layers-help-explain-its-hasan/)'s a little example i found), or as the previous answer pointed out, you can use SHAP.

Answer (score -1):

BERT is free. Any Sentiment Analysis model will achieve the task.

Comment: I know that BERT is free. I was actually asking about a tool similar to the one presented in the linked article (developed at Fiddler).